# delphi wordapp stop only one process

Tags: delphi

so, i made delphi application that convert from word to pdf with this code

```
...

Doc := Word.Documents.Open(FN, Param,Param, Param, Param, Param, Param, Param, Param, Param,Param,ParamFormat);

Doc.ExportAsFixedFormat(SaveDialog1.FileName, wdExportFormatPDF);

...
```

after convert process complete, there is WINWORD.EXE on process, if i do convert again, there is one WINWORD.EXE process again at task manager.
if i use Word.quit, it will close all WINWORD.EXE, including some words document that i open.

how can i stop the WINWORD.EXE that only call from my delphi application

thanks for your answer.

```
procedure TfrmConverterDoc.cxButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var Word, Doc, FN, Param, ParamFormat, save: OleVariant;
const wdExportFormatPDF = 17;
begin
if OpenDialog1.FileName = EmptyStr then
begin
  Application.MessageBox('Pilih File terlebih dahulu','Peringatan',mb_ok or MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
abort;
end
else
begin
FN := OpenDialog1.FileName;
Word := CreateOLEObject('Word.Application');
  try
if SaveDialog1.Execute then
begin
  if FileExists(SaveDialog1.FileName)then
  begin
    if Application.MessageBox('Overwrite?','Informasi',MB_YESNO or MB_ICONQUESTION)=idyes then
    begin
      ParamFormat := false;
      Param := EmptyParam;
      Doc := Word.Documents.Open(FN, Param,Param, Param, Param, Param, Param, Param, Param, Param,Param,ParamFormat);
      Doc.ExportAsFixedFormat(SaveDialog1.FileName, wdExportFormatPDF);
      Word.FileClose(1);
      //Doc.quit(false);
      //Word := Unassigned;
      ShowMessage('Convert Complete!');


    end
  end
  else
  begin
    ParamFormat := false;
    Param := EmptyParam;
    Doc := WordApplication1.Documents.Open(FN, Param,Param, Param, Param, Param, Param, Param, Param, Param,Param,ParamFormat);
    Doc.ExportAsFixedFormat(SaveDialog1.FileName, wdExportFormatPDF);
    //Doc := Unassigned;
    ShowMessage('Convert Complete!');
    //WordApplication1.ActiveDocument.Close(param,param,param);
  end
 end;
except
 on E : Exception do
  ShowMessage(E.ClassName+' error raised, with message : '+E.Message);
end;
end
end;
```

this is my full code for the application

Comment: Do you set Doc to Unassigned? I seem to remember that used to be something that you had to do.

Comment: yes, i tried it, but nothing happen the process is still remain

Comment: Does `Word.FileExit(1);` do what you want?

Comment: i got Method FileExit not supported erro..

Comment: `Word.FileClose(2)` should close the document then.

Comment: still got unsupported command. i use delphi 7 btw.

Comment: Last try, `Doc.Close(2)`.

Comment: Please show how you create the word automation object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close the WORD automation process use the statement `Word.Quit`.

code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

var
  Input, Output : String;
  Word, Doc, FN, Param, ParamFormat: OleVariant;

const wdExportFormatPDF = 17;

begin
 Input := 'c:\temp\test.doc';
 Output := 'c:\temp\test.pdf';
 Word := CreateOLEObject('Word.Application');
 try
  ParamFormat := false;
  Param := EmptyParam;
  Doc := Word.Documents.Open(Input, Param, Param, Param, Param, Param, Param, Param, Param, Param, Param, ParamFormat);
  Doc.ExportAsFixedFormat(Output, wdExportFormatPDF);
  Doc := Unassigned;
  Word.Quit;
  Word := Unassigned;
 except
  on E : Exception do
   ShowMessage(E.ClassName+' error raised, with message : '+E.Message);
 end;
end;
```

You claim that `Word.Quit` closes any active Word instance. I tested this and only the automation instance closes. 
My Environment:
- Windows 7 x64
- Delphi XE
- Office 2010

Answer (score 0):

Yes - it only stops one Word Instance, the one to which the variable is assigned.

This is not specifically a Delphi question because the word application is a COM object whose behaviour is the same however it is invoked.  For what its worth I have just written something in C# which you could easily adapt for your purposes.

```
    using MSWordApp = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application;
    .
    .
    .

    private MSWordApp _wordApp;
    private MSWordApp WordApp()
    {
        if (_wordApp == null)
            _wordApp = new MSWordApp();
        return _wordApp;
    }

    private void FreeWordApp()
    {
        if (_wordApp != null)
            ((_Application)_wordApp).Quit();
        _wordApp = null;
    }
```